# How small can a planet be and still have Earth-like gravity?

Tags: planet, earth-like-planet

A planet made from denser material than Earth might have equal gravity to Earth but a smaller radius. How small can a planet be and still have Earth gravity?

Ideally it should be habitable by humans, so not made of anything dangerous, radioactive or unstable.

Answer (score 9):

The [surface gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity) of a planet is very close to 
$$g=\frac{4\pi G}{3}\rho r.$$
With $g$ to be kept constant, and $\frac{4\pi G}{3}$ a constant, we need
$\rho_Pr_P=\rho_Er_E$, or
$$r_P=\frac{\rho_E}{\rho_P}r_E,$$
with $\rho_E=5.515 \mbox{ g}/\mbox{cm}^3$ the mean density of [Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth), $r_E=6371.0 \mbox{ km}$ the mean radius of Earth, $\rho_P=22.59\mbox{ g}/\mbox{cm}^3$ the density of densest natural element [osmium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium), and $r_P$ the radius of the fictive osmium planet.

Hence $$r_P=\frac{5.515}{22.59}r_E=0.2441~r_E=1555\mbox{ km}.$$

Some compression of the core of an osmium planet due to pressure is neglected.

Comment: Wow that's really small on the planet scale.

Comment: Yeah, that is small; that's half the size of Mercury.

Comment: Notably, despite having the same surface gravity of Earth, this "osmium-earth" has less than 0.1 times the mass.

Comment: Why would osmium be the limit though? Neutron stars are much denser. I realize you can't make a planet out of neutron star material, but surely there are things denser than osmium?

Comment: There's probobly not anything denser than Osmium in this context.  Certainly there's denser material, even in our solar-system.   The density at the core of our sun is about 150 g/CM3, but that's only possible under enormous pressure.   The density of a white dwarf is much greater than that and the density of a neutron star, much greater still, but if you're talking about 1 earth gravity, neutron star material or white dwarf material would probobly be unstable and fly apart.   There are some theories that say it could maintain integrity, but that's uncertain and I think unlikely

Comment: On that osmium planet with the Earth's gravity and about a quarter its radius there would be quite a difference between the weight of your feet and the weight of your head, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user30007 not really, the difference between your head and feet is still only ~0.00001%.